# Conditional inference trees vs traditional decision trees

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

Can anyone explain the primary differences between conditional inference trees (`ctree` from `party` package in R) compared to the more traditional decision tree algorithms (such as `rpart` in R)?

1. What makes CI trees different?
2. Strengths and weaknesses?

Update: I have looked at the paper by Horthorn et al that Chi refers to in the comments. I was not able to follow it completely - can anyone explain how variables are selected using permutations (e.g. what is an influence function)?

Comment: You mean an explanation that goes beyond what is described in [Hothorn's paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/vignettes/party.pdf)? I remember some nice illustrations from [Carolin Strobl](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~carolin/) at the [IMPS2009](http://www.thepsychometricscentre.com/) conference; I think there're some handouts on her website.

Comment: This link shows comparision between various forms of decision tree packages https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-tour-of-the-trees-and-forests/

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For what it's worth:

both `rpart` and `ctree` recursively perform [univariate splits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/does-rpart-use-multivariate-splits-by-default) of the dependent variable based on values on a set of covariates. `rpart` and related algorithms usually employ information measures (such as the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity)) for selecting the current covariate.

`ctree`, according to its authors (see [chl's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/930/chl) comments) avoids the following variable selection bias of `rpart` (and related methods): They tend to select variables that have many possible splits or many missing values. Unlike the others, `ctree` uses a significance test procedure in order to select variables instead of selecting the variable that maximizes an information measure (e.g. Gini coefficient).

The significance test, or better: the multiple significance tests computed at each start of the algorithm (select covariate - choose split - recurse) are [permutation tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29#Permutation_tests), that is, the "the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis is obtained by calculating all possible values of the test statistic under rearrangements of the labels on the observed data points." (from the wikipedia article).

Now for the test statistic: it is computed from transformations (including identity, that is, no transform) of the dependent variable and the covariates. You can choose any of a number of transformations for both variables. For the DV (Dependant Variable), the transformation is called the **influence function** you were asking about.

Examples (taken from the [paper](http://statmath.wu-wien.ac.at/%7Ezeileis/papers/Hothorn+Hornik+Zeileis-2006.pdf)):

- if both DV and covariates are numeric, you might select identity transforms and calculate correlations between the covariate and all possible permutations of the values of the DV. Then, you calculate the *p*-value from this permutation test and compare it with *p*-values for other covariates.
- if both DV and the covariates are nominal (unordered categorical), the test statistic is computed from a contingency table.
- you can easily make up other kinds of test statistics from any kind of transformations (including identity transform) from this general scheme.

small example for a permutation test in `R`:

```
require(gtools)
dv <- c(1,3,4,5,5); covariate <- c(2,2,5,4,5)
# all possible permutations of dv, length(120):
perms <- permutations(5,5,dv,set=FALSE) 
# now calculate correlations for all perms with covariate:
cors <- apply(perms, 1, function(perms_row) cor(perms_row,covariate)) 
cors <- cors[order(cors)]
# now p-value: compare cor(dv,covariate) with the 
# sorted vector of all permutation correlations
length(cors[cors>=cor(dv,covariate)])/length(cors)
# result: [1] 0.1, i.e. a p-value of .1
# note that this is a one-sided test
```

Now suppose you have a set of covariates, not only one as above. Then calculate *p*-values for each of the covariates like in the above scheme, and select the one with the smallest *p*-value. You want to calculate *p*-values instead of the correlations directly, because you could have covariates of different kinds (e.g. numeric and categorical).

Once you have selected a covariate, now explore all possible splits (or often a somehow restricted number of all possible splits, e.g. by requiring a minimal number of elements of the DV before splitting) again evaluating a permutation-based test.

`ctree` comes with a number of possible transformations for both DV and covariates (see the help for `Transformations` in the `party` package).

so generally the main difference seems to be that `ctree` uses a covariate selection scheme that is based on statistical theory (i.e. selection by permutation-based significance tests) and thereby avoids a potential bias in `rpart`, otherwise they seem similar; e.g. conditional inference trees can be used as base learners for Random Forests.

This is about as far as I can get. For more information, you really need to read the papers. Note that I strongly recommend that you really know what you're doing when you want to apply any kind of statistical analysis.

Comment: So would it be fair to say the following:
1. In principle, if significance tests were available and easy to compute for Gini, then any current decision tree builder could be augmented with these;
2. But in practice they are not available (i.e. very difficult/inefficient to compute) for most cases; 
3. The authors of CI trees chose one family of splitting criteria. This is not necessarily the best family for classification accuracy, but at least for it it's easy to compute significance;
4. And therefore a weakness of CI trees is that you are required to use this specific criterion?

Comment: @SheldonCooper: 1. and 2. may be a little over my head. I think you are right about 3. and 4.

Comment: @Wolf Thanks for this explanation it helped a lot! I was wondering, what is your take on the weights used - are these simply "1" when there is not a weighting of a given case?

Comment: This is a comment to wolf.rauch's answer but I can not post it as such because of my low reputation score. Would be thankful if someone could repost it. Could you clarify the term "Transformation"? From the help in the `party` package it looks like the standard `apply()` function to me. It leaves me with the choice of what I should do to IVs and DV but I don't understand the purpose of doing so. I have another question to this part: > "if both DV and covariates are numeric, you might select identity transforms and calculate correlations between the covariate (...)

Comment: (...) and all possible permutations of the values of the DV"

All possible permutations of the values of DV? It takes over 130 seconds to find all possible permutations of 10 elements. This would make CI trees useless when you have more than 20 observations. -- added by a moderator.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does DV stands for?

Comment: @mythicalprogrammer dependent variable, I think