# Linear statistic for measuring association in the party R package

Tags: r, cart

I had asked a general question about conditional inference trees via party a while [back](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/conditional-inference-trees-vs-traditional-decision-trees) and gotten a great reply.

I am revisiting this procedure and trying to make sense of the linear statistic that is being used (Hothorn et al., Unbiased Recursive Partitioning: A Conditional Inference Framework, Research Report Series, 2004, [page 4, equation (1)](http://epub.wu.ac.at/676/1/document.pdf)).

[image]

I am not at all clear how this statistic is calculated. Can anyone help?

Here is what it seems to me that if

- $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$ are the identity functions
- and there is a predictor $x$ and a response $y$, both numeric, the statistic is simply a scalar. This is not what is shown, so I am wrong :)

Example data:

```
x<-c(1,3,4,67,32,23,3,12,4)
y<-c(43,23,45,22,12,465,6,54,3)
w<-rep(1,9)

T<-0
for (i in 1:length(y))
{

  T<-T+(w[i]*x[i]*y[i])  

}
T #13523
```

I *THINK* the result needs to be a vector of length 81.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to answer my own question for completeness. I seems I was reading the p and q values incorrectly and in fact, I believe my trivial example to be correct: i.e that T does equal  13523.

I stumbled upon the vignette for the coin [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/vignettes/LegoCondInf.pdf) and learned that this package contains the function `independence_test` that appears the same as the idea from `ctree`. The coin function exposes the expectation vector and covariance matrix shown above  (Hothorn et al., Unbiased Recursive Partitioning: A Conditional Inference Framework, Research Report Series, 2004, page 4, equation (1)).

Here is the R code used to verify the calculation of 13523.

```
library(coin)
library(party)
library(Formula)

x<-c(1,3,4,67,32,23,3,12,4)
y<-c(43,23,45,22,12,465,6,54,3)
w<-rep(1,9)
num_test<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))


c<-independence_test(y~x, data = num_test,ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = id_trafo), teststat="max")
show(c)

statistic(c,type = c("test")) #0.263028
expectation(c)
covariance(c)
variance(c)


T<-0
for (i in 1:length(y))
{

  T<-T+(w[i]*x[i]*y[i])  

}
T #13523


abs((T-expectation(c))/sqrt(variance(c))) #0.263028 matches above!

#now use ctree
xy_tree<-ctree(y~x, data = num_test, controls = ctree_control(teststat="max", mincriterion=0.001, minsplit=1))
nodes(xy_tree,1)[[1]][3] #statistic is #0.263028 matches above!
```

I also confirmed with an example using a factor as the independent variable (with dummy coding).